# ROR + Slots of days from start of week to end of the week

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my application, I want to show the slot of days for a single month. For example today is  27th Feb. Here

I want to generate slots from

```
[ 24 Febuary - 02 March]
[ 03 March - 09 March]
[ 10 March - 16 March]
[ 17 March - 23 March]
[ 24 March - 30 March]
```

Now its five slots. So according to todays date I want to put all this inside any array. I am not getting the way to resolve it.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date_current = Date.current

5.times.map do |n|
  date = (date_current+ (n*7).days)
  [date.at_beginning_of_week, date.at_end_of_week]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a lit change because I need start of week from Sunday.

[image]

```
date_current = Date.current

5.times.map do |n|
  date = (date_current+ (n*7).days)
  [date.at_beginning_of_week-1.day, date.at_end_of_week-1.day]
end
```

subtraction of one day from beginning of week and end of week.